# Bash: Processing files with special characters

Tags: bash, special-characters

I have a bash scripts which converts my music library into mp3 format and copy those to a different directory. As the directories and files partly contain special characters like (, ), &, the script fails.

I have set:

```
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
```

The code of the encode command is the following:

```
ffmpeg -i ${f} -ab 192k ${SDCARD}/$(basename ${t})/$(basename ${d})/$(basename ${f%.*}.mp3)
```

The file structure is the following $SDCARD/$t/$d/$f which will be like:
/Volumes/MUSIC/Jessie Ware/Devotion (US Version)/09 If You're Never Gonna Move.mp3

Any suggestions?

Thanks
Lukas

Comment: use quotes. `"$var"`

Comment: what is the problem or question ?

Comment: `${f}` needs the quotes too (and doesn't need `{}`). And you can keep variables in the same token in just one pair, e.g. `"$SDCard/$(basename "$t")/..."`

Comment: @Kevin - you should consider posting as an answer, so that the OP can mark it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is generally good practice to quote your variables when referencing them, to prevent exactly the type of problem you are experiencing. See http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html to learn more.

An example:

```
jed@MBP:~$ FOO="one two three"
jed@MBP:~$ for i in $FOO; do echo The value of i is\: $i;done
The value of i is: one
The value of i is: two
The value of i is: three

jed@MBP:~$ for i in "$FOO"; do echo The value of i is\: $i;done
The value of i is: one two three
```

(If Kevin ever comes back and makes his comment an answer, you should mark his as correct, so he gets the credit for answering first.)